# Tikz how to draw from a node to the margin of a page

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,calc}

\newcommand*{\MyNode}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm,
    S/.style = {signal, fill=orange, 
        signal to=east,
        minimum height=3ex,
        text depth=0.25ex,
        inner sep=7,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries}
    ]
    \node (n1) [S] {\color{white} \huge\textbf{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont{#1}}};
    \draw [line width=0.7mm, black] (n1.east) -- (\textwidth-3cm, 0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont}{}{0em}
{\MyNode{#1}}
%

\begin{document}
    \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm, bottom=1cm}
    \section{Education}
    \section{Personal Projects}
\end{document}
```

producing the output

[image]

##### I want to find a way to make the lines extend up until the right margin of the page.

---

### Things I have tried

I have looked up online on ways to express the right page margin absolute position as a variable in `Tikz` but with no success. I have further searched how to store the value of the width of a given shape from within `Tikz` such that I can do `\textwidth - \shapewidth` but with no success either.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,calc}

\newcommand*{\MyNode}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
    node distance = 2mm,
    S/.style = {signal, fill=orange, 
        signal to=east,
        minimum height=3ex,
        text depth=0.25ex,
        inner sep=7,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries}
    ]
    \node (n1) [S] {\color{white} \huge\textbf{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont{#1}}};
    \draw [line width=0.7mm, black] (n1) -- (n1 -| current page text area.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont}{}{0em}
{\MyNode{#1}}
%

\begin{document}
    \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm, bottom=1cm}
    \section{Education}
    \section{Personal Projects}
\end{document}
```

[image: Orange nodes with horizontal lines to right margin]

Comment: Thank you ! I would've never found that !